# Find all square numbers $n$ such that $f(n)$ is a square number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Find all the square numbers $n$ such that $ f(n)=n^3+2n^2+2n+4$ is also a perfect square.

I have tried but I don't know how to proceed after factoring $f(n)$ into $(n+2)(n^2+2)$. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Does $n=0$ work?

Comment: Both $n=0, 1$ work but I need to find all of them.

Comment: You should probably rewrite your question, then.

Comment: Then edit your question.  Your question reads "find **a** square number..." implying only one solution is necessary.  If you want to find all of them, edit it to say "find **all** square numbers..."  The two questions are very different.

Comment: Factoring is a good start to finding all possible solutions.  Ask yourself when $n+2$ and $n^2 + 2$ can have a common factor.  If not, then the product is a perfect square only when both of them are perfect squares.  Also you might let $n=k^2$ to enforce that $n$ should be a perfect square.

Comment: Note the fact that since $\gcd(n^2+2,n+2)=\gcd(6,n+2)$, the following cases are possible. 

$$n+2=a^2, n^2+2=b^2$$$$n+2=2b^2, n^2+2=2a^2$$ $$n+2=3a^2, n^2+2=3b^2$$$$n+2=6a^2, n^2+2=6b^2$$
The first case is impossible since $n^2 \equiv 0,1\pmod 4$.

Answer (score 7):

Your factoring seems to appear difficult to solve.

Instead say $n=t^2$.

If $t>1$, note that $f(t^2)=t^6+2t^4+2t^2+4$, and that $(t^3+t+1)^2=t^6+2t^4+t^2+2t^3+2t+1>f(t^2) >t^6+2t^4+t^2=(t^3+t)^2$ (since $2t^3-t^2+2t-3>0$ from [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2t%5E3-t%5E2%2B2t-3))

If $t<-1$, note that $(t^3+t-1)^2=t^6+2t^4+t^2-2t^3-2t+1>f(t^2) >t^6+2t^4+t^2=(t^3+t)^2$  (since $-2t^3-t^2-2t-3>0$ from [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2t%5E3-t%5E2-2t-3))

So $t=-1,0,1$.

Comment: To simplify this argument, note that we can assume $t \ge 0$ since we only care about $n$.  This is essentially completing the square, a very useful technique whenever we are looking for squares of the form $f(n)$ where $f$ is a polynomial of even degree with a leading coefficient that's square.